# Using BYTE PTR to determine the address size when using Data Segment

Tags: pointers, assembly, x86, bootloader, mbr

I am trying to figure out an MBR code (16-bit assembly code in real mode) and I have these lines :

```
mov    si,0x7cd8
lods   al,BYTE PTR ds:[si]
```

What happens in real time, is that the physical address is 'D8' - How do I know that ? Because this is used for loading a string and printing it to the string. and that`s the first thing I can see when I run this program and these are the first lines of the code.

My question is about the second line, is it that the physical address I get is because of the calculation being done to get the physical address (segment * 16 + offset) or that the BYTE PTR tells that the SI address will be type of BYTE and the type of the data we will read is of type byte ?

Comment: The type doesn't matter, it's because of `segment*16+offset`. The physical address is `0x7cd8` with `ds=0` or else it wouldn't work ;)

Comment: The `BYTE PTR` is only required when the target size is not evident. And your `lods ...` is more usually written as `lodsb`. Finally, `ds` is the default segment register for `lodsxx` anyway, so the segment override is unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second line

```
lods   al,BYTE PTR ds:[si]
```

is simply the disassemblers output of the instruction `LODSB`(load a byte from the address `DS:SI` and `INC SI`).

In assembler you would simple write `LODSB` which means

> load a byte from the address DS:SI to the byte register AL and increment SI afterwards

Concerning the segment issue of `DS`: of course the accessed address is calculated by the formula `(segment * 16 + offset)`, but you can set `DS` to anything you want and *only* `SI` is incremented (post-read) by the instruction, nevertheless.

`DS` can have any value.

Comment: I understand now. Concerning DS is not being changed thorugh all the program manually, it will always stay 0 (default) ?

Comment: @sitoNz: I (seriously) don't know. The value of `DS` will surely be defined somewhere before these two lines are executed. Assuming a default value would be (very) bad practice in a MBR.